# select sum from table where field is in another table with field

Tags: mysql, join, sum

maybe the title is a little confusing, so here is the query i am trying to get to work:

```
select sum(amount+discount) from `payments` where `id_invoice` in (select `id` from `invoices` where `id_client`='$id'
```

where `$id` is the `id` of a client from the `clients` table

here are the 3 table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_client` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `po_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `terms` text NOT NULL,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Draft',
  `date_saved` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `issue_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `due_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cancelled` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `tax_percentage` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '20',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_invoice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `the_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `method` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `receipt_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discount` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

so i want to get the total amount of payments + discounts per client...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing with the current query?

Comment: the only problem I see in the current query is a missing close parenthesis, I assume that's just a copying error.

Comment: hahaha the closing parenthesis was the issue. im a noob.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes it is better to join the tables together and then perform your sum while grouping on the clients name:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(p.amount + p.discount) AS MyCalc
FROM invoices AS i
  JOIN payments AS p ON p.id_invoice = i.id'
  JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = i.id_client
GROUP BY c.name
```

You can then add you WHERE clause to restrict the results further:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(p.amount + p.discount) AS MyCalc
FROM invoices AS i
  JOIN payments AS p ON p.id_invoice = i.id'
  JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = i.id_client
WHERE id_client = $id
GROUP BY c.name
```